# Align Datasheet View Content to the Top

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, custom-list, rich-text

I have a custom list with a Datasheet View. Nothing fancy here, just single text columns (enriched text), multi-line text (enriched text) columns, and a few date columns. When I view list items in this Datasheet View, item content is displaying across columns with what appears to be an alignment of "middle". So as a user viewing view items, my eye has to travel up and down to read the content across the row. I want all content across all columns to align at the top. What can I do to achieve this?
Thx in advance.